# How to Sync photos from SkyDrive to iPhoto

Tags: macos, iphoto, windows-phone, onedrive

I'm running OSX (Lion) as my home computer, and use iPhoto ('11) for photo management.

Windows Phone 7.5 automatically uploads photos to SkyDrive when taken - and I'd like to automatically sync these photos into iPhoto.

Anybody got a good idea of how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Get Skydrive app for Mac
https://apps.live.com/skydrive

I also have my files in iPhoto. You can just copy those files to the designated SkyDrive folder (or subfolder of).

Still would like to find a way to get away from copying...

Comment: This is pretty much the answer - as my aim is to sync _from_ Skydrive _to_ iPhoto. I've set up the Skydrive app, then used Hazel to automatically import any photos in the Skydrive camera roll folder.

The downside I've found is - Skydrive photos aren't full resolution. So I've gone back to manual imports.

Comment: I tried using SkyDrive for online photo storage last week. However SkyDrive is badly lacking lots of features. The most annoying one is that there's no way to (easily) rearrange photos based on date. At this point in time all you can do is rearrange them by manually typing in numbers in a small box below every picture. Horrible user interface, Microsoft. :-P So I kind of reverted to Picasa, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

You can either download all your pictures from the phone, or just pull them off skydrive.

Click the folder that all your pictures are stored and click Download.  It will download the folder as a zip file.

Comment: Thanks - i'm already manually importing from the phone. I've edited the question clarify that I'm hoping for an automated solution.